# How to protect specific uploaded files from being accessed by non-logged-in users in WP-multisite

Tags: multisite, uploads, htaccess

I have a question that I thought the below thread would provide the answer to, but things in WP have changed so it doesn't quite do it, although it helped my understanding of things.

[How to protect uploads in multisite if user is not logged in?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63410/how-to-protect-uploads-in-multisite-if-user-is-not-logged-in)

Basically, I would like to not serve files that are attached to private posts unless the user is actually logged in. That apparently requires that all request go through a php file that basically does what the ms-files code die before it was removed from WP multisite in 3.5 (as I found out). The first approach in this answer

[How to Protect Uploads, if User is not Logged In?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/how-to-protect-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in)

apprently still works for single site installations but as the rewrite code and the file structure for multisite have changed, the modifications in the first thread I linked to no longer work.

Frank Bueltge's approach (the second answer in the thread) even incorporates a check for the attachment's parent (and would thus allow a check for post_status) but somehow I can't get it to work. And somehow, the modified code he includes in his plugin "authenticator" also don't seem to work.

https://github.com/bueltge/Authenticator/blob/master/inc/class-Authenticator_Protect_Upload.php

I understand that serving files through php is bad for performance, but as far as I understand, this is the only way a login-check/status-check can be logically done. Sadly, I can't seem to get any of the solutations to work for a multisite installation, given the changes since the removal of ms-files.php.

I'd really appreciate any help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The class inside the Authenticator plugin is a starter point, not ready to use. I have include this as open issues. The problem is the enhancement of the .htaccess, not easy for a plugin.

Comment: I wonder how a multisite rewrite rule would have to look to either use a modified ms-files.php with the new file structue or how it would have to look to use your class. I have to say that I don't entirely understand how the class is called through the http request and gets the $file to perform the checks. How would I hook the class in?

Comment: The problem on the class is, that is was fired on init-Hook, to late for downloads outside the load of WP. You need a rule in the htaccess, that fired the class.

Comment: Right, and that's why a rewrite rule is needed in .htaccess that directs all file requests to a php file, à la ms-files.php. But what would that rule look like for a multisite installation after WP 3.5 when ms-files was removed for new installs and the rewrite rules look different?

Comment: Is the currently only way to protect files in multisite setups to install an older version and then update to ms-files is preserved and can still be modified?