# Restrict directory listing to only logged in users

Tags: content-restriction

I am using directory listing with http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/ theme. Which is obviously not part of WordPress. I am looking for a way to allow only registered subscribers to access + download content from those directories.

I have looked into `<?php auth_redirect(); ?>` but it seems like it only works if the page/post is already part of WordPress ecosystem.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try configuring your server to pass or “proxy” all requests to your directory through a php script that can check if the user is logged-in.

Check out the following answer for an example of how to do this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37743/48165

Comment: i am accepting your answer because it does link a solution that meets the problem I am facing. But my issues is more convulated than I previously thought - so I will ask another question with more details. Thanks for your time.