# Restricted images only for logged user. (hidden url)

Tags: functions, images, content-restriction

Im looking  for way to create page where only logged in user can see images, but images cant be index by browser, cant be accessed by not logged in user. 
Simply, if logged in user copy image link, and not logged in user try see it, he should see 404 or some other redirect, logged in user should be able to see this image. (Link should not expire). And Image can be downloaded ofc. :)

And it is way to prevent wordpress to index images? (They should be privated, and cant be access by any sinply url like www.site.com/wp-content/media/image.jpg etc ;)

Answer (score 0):

Been done before
You should take some time to research your issue here and be sure to read the site help topics especially How do I ask a good question?

We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Find Answer Here

[How to Protect Uploads, if User is not Logged In?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/how-to-protect-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in)

More explanation here
http://0to5.com/protecting-wordpress-media-uploads-unless-user-is-logged-in/

Comment: Sorry, i looked for it. just not found this one ;)
Im just going to test it.