# Protecting direct access to PDF and ZIP unless user logged in (without plugin)

Tags: uploads, htaccess, media, media-library, security

Working on a WordPress support site which has registered only user content, including uploaded PDF and ZIP files.

I'm looking for a way to prevent direct access to those PDFs and ZIP files inside the wp-content/uploads directory without the use of a plugin.

Reading through older questions, this is REALLY close (but comments are closed): https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37743/18608 as it detects direct access to the file, then does some login to save the file requested and check to see if the user is logged in. If not, they get redirected to the WordPress login. If they are logged in, then it loads the file.

This is the original htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, the script blocks access to **all** files inside the wp-content/uploads directory, including images - so unless the user is logged in, even blog post images (which don't need protected) are hidden on the front-end.

I'm trying to revise the RewriteRule to check for **only** PDF or ZIP files, so that the dl-file.php file only gets called if it's a PDF or ZIP being requested.

I've tried the following, but it returns "404-File not found." when accessing a PDF or ZIP when the user is logged in, so even though the file type check appears to be working, the dl-file.php check is failing.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/([^/]*\.(pdf|zip))$ filecheck.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How would I revise this so that it only calls the dl-file.php if it's a pdf or zip file being requested, but still pass the correct info to dl-file.php?

Thank you,
Jonathon

```
/*
 * dl-file.php
 *
 * Protect uploaded files with login.
 * 
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/protect-wordpress-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in
 * 
 * @author hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com/>
 * @license GPL-3.0+
 * @registry SPDX
 */

require_once('wp-load.php');

is_user_logged_in() || auth_redirect();

list($basedir) = array_values(array_intersect_key(wp_upload_dir(), array('basedir' => 1)))+array(NULL);

$file =  rtrim($basedir,'/').'/'.str_replace('..', '', isset($_GET[ 'file' ])?$_GET[ 'file' ]:'');
if (!$basedir || !is_file($file)) {
    status_header(404);
    die('404 &#8212; File not found.');
}

$mime = wp_check_filetype($file);
if( false === $mime[ 'type' ] && function_exists( 'mime_content_type' ) )
    $mime[ 'type' ] = mime_content_type( $file );

if( $mime[ 'type' ] )
    $mimetype = $mime[ 'type' ];
else
    $mimetype = 'image/' . substr( $file, strrpos( $file, '.' ) + 1 );

header( 'Content-Type: ' . $mimetype ); // always send this
if ( false === strpos( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Microsoft-IIS' ) )
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $file ) );

$last_modified = gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime( $file ) );
$etag = '"' . md5( $last_modified ) . '"';
header( "Last-Modified: $last_modified GMT" );
header( 'ETag: ' . $etag );
header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 100000000 ) . ' GMT' );

// Support for Conditional GET
$client_etag = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) ? stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) : false;

if( ! isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] ) )
    $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] = false;

$client_last_modified = trim( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] );
// If string is empty, return 0. If not, attempt to parse into a timestamp
$client_modified_timestamp = $client_last_modified ? strtotime( $client_last_modified ) : 0;

// Make a timestamp for our most recent modification...
$modified_timestamp = strtotime($last_modified);

if ( ( $client_last_modified && $client_etag )
    ? ( ( $client_modified_timestamp >= $modified_timestamp) && ( $client_etag == $etag ) )
    : ( ( $client_modified_timestamp >= $modified_timestamp) || ( $client_etag == $etag ) )
    ) {
    status_header( 304 );
    exit;
}

// If we made it this far, just serve the file
readfile( $file );
```

Comment: Note that if you put this comment at the top of the answer `/** Plugin Name: Zip Plugin **/` it becomes a plugin, but what you're asking looks like it has nothing to do with WordPress, a pure Apache HTAccess question

Comment: Thanks - the original post I was referencing contains the dl-file.php with login check / redirect that is WordPress specific - that's what I'm having trouble getting to work. Trying to check for pdf and zip, and still getting the conditional login check to work for the redirect portion. I've added more details for clarity.

Comment: I just noticed, you changed `dl-file.php` to `filecheck.php`? Presumably this is the same file?

Comment: Thank you, it is - I had changed it here, but kept it the same for the example. I missed my reference to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
> RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/([^/]*\.(pdf|zip))$ filecheck.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

This actually looks OK, except if you have additional subdirectories within the `/uploads` directory? An alternative is to include an additional condition on the original rule that only rewrites the request if the request ends in `.pdf` or `.zip`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf|zip)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It shouldn't really matter, but make sure this goes *before* the WordPress front-controller.

Comment: Thank you - this makes sense. I'm testing here, but for some reason it's not picking up on the login condition, so the PDF is loading when logged out?

Comment: Thank you, MrWhite - this was the right direction. I couldn't get REQUEST_URL to work in the first RewriteCond, but changing to RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(pdf|zip)$ did the trick.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry that was a typo, it should be `REQUEST_URI`, not `REQUEST_URL`! (I've updated my answer.) Glad you got it working!

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your trick. I have a question : If i'm not logged, i'm redirected to login page when i put a  URL with PDF file on the browser. Is it possible to redirect to 404 page? thanks again.

Comment: @sampaii You would need to do that in your download/authentication script (in PHP)... if the user is not logged in then respond with a 404 instead of redirecting - which is presumably currently being triggered by your script - if you have followed the example above?

Comment: #mrwhite, sorry I see rightnow your message. it's an issue with this method. when I'm login to the backend and tape the URL of any pdf file. I'm redirected to 404 page. any idea please?