# How to block access to a folder inside of wp-content for non logged in users?

Tags: php, htaccess, content-restriction

I have a custom folder inside of wp-content where I'm uploading media. I need to block direct access to this folder unless the user is logged in.

Is there any way to do this? I've searched but have only come up with blocking directory browsing using .htaccess.

Comment: read this : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281500/protecting-direct-access-to-pdf-and-zip-unless-user-logged-in-without-plugin

Comment: This is super close. Although, I'm not using PDF or ZIP files. These are regular HTML files with assets. I did try to access it and unfortunately, even if I'm logged in, I can't.