# I want to create custom post in which user can share files like PDF & DOCx

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I want to create custom post type for users in which user who is login can share files by selecting categories like below form..
[image]

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Can i create such post type

Comment: To create CPT take a look [here](https://generatewp.com/post-type/)

Comment: How can user can share files in post tyoe

Comment: Perhaps you start doing some research, following leads like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/283156/15605) and others shown by duckduckgo/google/startpage and/or the codex.