# Rrestrict access to static pages if user is not logged in

Tags: directory

I have a folder on my WordPress site (named documentation; see screenshot), where I host a bunch of static HTML pages. How can I restrict access to the folder, so only logged in users are allowed  to see it's content?

I tried to implement this solution
[How to Protect Uploads, if User is not Logged In?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/how-to-protect-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in) but when ths user is logged in, he gets a 404.

Thanks in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi im very noob in wordpress but maybe this can give you some google results:
Wp_nopriv
Wp_priv

I think these were things for AJAX(the thing i just have experienced). But they had to do with the user being logged in or not. I wish you goodluck.