# Using "wordpress_logged_in" to restrict direct access to uploads folder in 2021

Tags: htaccess, security

I am looking at ways to restrict direct access to the Wordpress Uploads folder. I've read a handful of Stackoverflow and blog posts about using "wordpress_logged_in" in .htaccess to check if a person is logged in and if they are not to restrict them. See example of a snippet below.

However, I also read a post that was written almost 10 years ago that it would be preferable to do this via PHP as checking for a cookie isn't very secure and could be hackable. However, since then Wordpress has improved how cookies are done and are more secure as I understand it.

Old Stackoverflow thread here.

[How to Protect Uploads, if User is not Logged In?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/how-to-protect-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in)

How hackable is checking for a cookie if a person is logged in? Is the idea here that a person could Brute Force the cookie? For me this solution is more straightforward and something I can easily wrap my head around.

Htacess Example here - Check to see if a person is logged in:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in_([a-zA-Z0-9_]*) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Check to see if a person is logged in:
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)
>     RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in_([a-zA-Z0-9_]*) [NC]
>     RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

The same applies as it did 10 years ago. This code in `.htaccess` doesn't have anything to do with how WordPress might be setting cookies. And this does not "check to see if a person is logged in". It simply checks that a string that matches the regex `wordpress_logged_in_([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)` does not appear anywhere in the `Cookie` header. The "problem" here is that anyone can create a request that passes a value in the `Cookie` header that passes your test. Since it is well known that WP sets such a cookie then it is not difficult to guess.

The *only* way to check that the request is "logged in" to WordPress is to use PHP.

---

*Aside:* The first `RewriteCond` directive that checks against `REQUEST_FILENAME` is superfluous since it simply checks against *anything*. The `NC` flag on the second condition should not be used in such checks, since you are now unnecessarily increasing the range of strings that would pass the test (eg. `wOrDpReSs_LoGgEd_In_` would pass). Consequently, including `A-Z` in the *hash* portion is unnecessarily - the *hash* is always lowercase (and always 32 chars long AFAIK). The `L` flag is not required when used with the `F` flag (it is implied) and the regex `.*` will block all requests if that cookie does not exist, not just access to the WordPress uploads folder. You should also avoid using the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper for anything security related, since a "failure" in your server config (ie. mod_rewrite being erroneously disabled) would allow unrestricted access, instead of breaking with an error (which would be preferable).

So, the above should be written like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(?:^|;\s)wordpress_logged_in_[a-z0-9_]{32}=
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/ - [F]
```

The regex `(?:^|;\s)wordpress_logged_in_[a-z0-9_]{32}=` specifically checks for that cookie *name* (more specific), rather than a string that occurs anywhere in the `Cookie` header (too general).

(Although, to clarify, this is really no more "secure" than the original code snippet.)

Comment: Thanks. I marked this as the correct answer as you went above and beyond. Much appreciated.

Comment: Question for you. Reviewing the post about verifying via PHP. In my case I need to lockdown most of the design assets as well. Like header images. How much overhead do you think this will add to page speed?

Comment: @Work-Together2013 "How much overhead do you think this will add to page speed?" - The only way is to test it. It depends on your server and how it's implemented. It's certainly a significant overhead compared to simply serving a static resource (often from client-side cache), but it may still be perfectly OK. Consider "caching" the authenticated state in the server-side session to avoid potentially repeated DB checks for multiple resources on the same page. You'll also need to ensure that client-side caching is disabled, which will further impact performance.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has changed here. The reason it was a bad idea 10 years ago is because it’s a bad idea. Not because of a flaw in WordPress.

With your htaccess example all I would need to do is create a cookie with the name `wordpress_logged_in_a` and now I have access.

This is not something WordPress *could* improve. To know whether a user should have access you need to know whether the cookie is for a valid session, and that information is in the database. The existence of the cookie proves nothing on its own.

Answer (score 2):

> How hackable is checking for a cookie if a person is logged in? Is the
> idea here that a person could Brute Force the cookie? For me this
> solution is more straightforward and something I can easily wrap my
> head around.

I think you can fool it with a simple command line curl request like:

```
curl --cookie "..." https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/test.jpg
```

containing a cookie that matches the test in

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in_([a-zA-Z0-9_]*) [NC]
```

That's why e.g. Moodle opens the uploaded user files via PHP to handle the user permissions.