# How to make media upload private?

Tags: plugins, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Protect Uploads, if User is not Logged In?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/how-to-protect-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in)

I know how to mark a Page or Post as visible only to members, using the Member Access plugin.  This way, the public cannot view them; instead, you have to log in to see the page.

How do I mark a PDF or other Media upload as visible only to members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching this Stack, I can see two possible solutions for this question (not tested).

#### One

The answer is not fully developed, but can provide some insight.
[Restricting access to files within a specific folder](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/6774/12615)

#### Two

[How to Protect Uploads, if User is not Logged In?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/37144/12615)
*Frank Bueltge's* answer seems interesting but the code is quite complex. As he himself admits his english is nasty, but I can assure his coding skills are superb :)

And the answer provided by *hakre* could be operational:

- Protecting one or more folders inside `/wp-content/uploads/` through `.htaccess` as detailed there.
- Moving the desired files to this upload folders according to User or Post-ID, and for that the answer I provide to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/25894/12615) should do it. And, with the examples provided, maybe you can think of other kind of filtering.